# Is there a way to add transitions to a ContentControl in Windows Phone 7.1?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I've searched all over but it seems like no one has figured out a way (or at least written about a way) to add transitions to a ContentControl (or equivalent) in **Silverlight for Windows Phone**.

I'm using Caliburn Micro, and I have a Screen Conductor that activates different user controls. All I want is a simple slide effect between activations, forward and back. You can do this in WPF but not in SL4WP it seems like.

The other alternative is to switch to using navigation between these views, but then I lose the "master-detail" style view model. I'd be open to an answer that kept my intention but used page navigation instead (since then I could use the Slide transitions from the Windows Phone Toolkit).

It's a step-by-step style conductor, I need to lead the user through a 2-3 step process, allowing them to go back or cancel out, each step using data from the previous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it cannot be done? There are various blog posts and articles on the internet that indicate that the `TransitioningContentControl` is part of the [Silverlight for Window Phone Toolkit](http://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/SlickThought/Windows-Phone-7-April-CTP-and-TransitioningContentControl).

Note that 'Silverlight' and 'Silverlight for Windows Phone' are different things, so you must download the right toolkit.

Comment: I know I have the latest toolkit in my project and that control is definitely not there; however, let me try out the source included in that article to see what I can find.

Comment: Well, that got me much farther. I copied the relevant files to my solution and now it transitions. But there are other issues with using the VSM as noted here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932703/sliding-transition-animation-between-screens-in-caliburn-micro). For example, if I click a button that transitions back/forward before the transition is done, I get into a bad state like that post mentions. It would be nice to find a solution ala that `TransitionPresenter` otherwise this may lead to more headaches than it's worth.

Comment: Alright, I think have the state management figured out. Using Caliburn, I can guard and override the activation of items and I can query the `IsTransitioning` property of the control. This seems to work well enough to prevent any unwanted state changes.